# Методы OnCollision2D срабатывают только один раз

Tags: unity3d

Создал два метода: `OnCollisionStay2D` и `OnCollisionExit2D`, код в них выполняется только один раз

```
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collis)
{
    if (colis.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        myBool = false;
    }
}

void OnCollisionStay2D (Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collis.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        myBool = true;
    }
}
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы условия проверялись вместе с вызовом методов

Comment: что значит "чтобы условия проверялись вместе с вызовом методов"?

Comment: а сколько раз оно должно вызываться, если у тебя меняется булевая переменная?